# IR: How do you match documents based on index values and return the document?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, information-retrieval

I have a pandas data frame `df` which has the top 10 documents from a corpus ranked based on their BM25 score, and indexed by their `Doc_ID`.

| Doc_ID | Rank | BM25 Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | 3.3472 |
| 5678 | 2 | 3.3238 |

I also have a list `documents` containing all of the documents paired up with their `Doc_ID`, such that the list is in the following form: `[['First Doc_ID', 'First doc text], ['Second Doc_ID', 'Second doc text], ...]`.

I need to take the `Doc_ID` for the top 3 ranked documents in `df`, and match each one with the corresponding `Doc_ID` in `documents` and print out the document text. I know how to get the `Doc_ID` for a particular rank from `df` by doing `df.index[df['Rank'] == 1][0]`, but I'm unsure how to go from there to get the corresponding document text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your list to DataFrame and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
documents = [[1234, 'First doc text'],
             [5678, 'Second doc text'],
             [5679, 'Third doc text'],
             [5680, 'Fourth doc text']]

(df[df['Rank'].le(3)]
 .merge(pd.DataFrame(documents,
                     columns=['Doc_ID', 'Text']),
        on='Doc_ID')
)
```

output:

```
   Doc_ID  Rank  BM25 Score             Text
0    1234     1      3.3472   First doc text
1    5678     2      3.3238  Second doc text
2    5679     3      3.2000   Third doc text
```

used input:

```
   Doc_ID  Rank  BM25 Score
0    1234     1      3.3472
1    5678     2      3.3238
2    5679     3      3.2000
3    5680     4      3.1000
```

Alternatively, if you want a list using python:

```
top3 = set(df.loc[df['Rank'].le(3), 'Doc_ID'])
out = [text for ID, text in documents if ID in top3]
```

output: `['First doc text', 'Second doc text', 'Third doc text']`